# Matplotlib Quiver Plot Fails when Origin is at (0,0)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code, which is supposed to draw arrows in different directions sharing the same origin at (0,0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 8, endpoint=False)
X = np.zeros_like(angles)
Y = np.zeros_like(angles)
U = np.cos(angles)
V = np.sin(angles)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles='xy', headlength=2)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

However it produces a

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide lengths = np.hypot(*dxy.T) / eps
```

in matplotlib\quiver.py:603 and only one arrow instead of 8 is drawn:
! [image]

What I expect is the following:
[image]

Which can be achieved by setting X or Y or both to something not equal to zero. Is this expected behaviour and how can I draw a quiver plot with all arrows originating at (0,0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is being triggered by [this line](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e5a85f960b2d47eac371cff709b830d52c36d267/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py#L603), so `eps` is zero.  `eps` gets set [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e5a85f960b2d47eac371cff709b830d52c36d267/lib/matplotlib/quiver.py#L618) based on the data limits of your plot.  So if you have other things to add to this plot, you could try adding those first so they set non-zero data limits.

Alternatively, note that this loop is entered by having set `angles='xy'`.  Since you set your aspect ratio to "equal", angles in screen space are the same as angles in data space.  So you do not gain anything by setting `angles='xy'` and can just take it out:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

angles = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 8, endpoint=False)
X = np.zeros_like(angles)
Y = np.zeros_like(angles)
U = np.cos(angles)
V = np.sin(angles)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, headlength=2)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you specify your angles in degrees, you can pass those directly to quiver and U and V are only used to determine the length of the arrows.  This gives the same plot as above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

angles = np.linspace(0, 360, 8, endpoint=False)
X = np.zeros_like(angles)
Y = np.zeros_like(angles)
U = np.ones_like(angles)
V = np.ones_like(angles)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, angles=angles, headlength=2)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```